# JTabbedPane TabComponent default tab highlighting

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtextfield, jtabbedpane

I have a question regarding custom tab components in swing.

The following code will add 3 custom tab components:

```
public class TabbedExample extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createUI();
      }
    }
  }
  public static void createUI() {
    try {
      for(LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tab Test");
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(256,200));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new TabbedExample());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public TabbedExample() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField());
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField());
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
      tabPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      tabPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tabPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("Tab " + i);
      textField.setOpaque(false);
      textField.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      textField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
      tabPanel.add(label);
      tabPanel.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
      pane.setTabComponentAt(i, tabPanel);
    }
    add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

the problem now is that the default tab behaviour stops working. normally, when you move your mouse over a tab, it automagically gets highlight by changing the background color. but as soon as the `JTextField` is hit, the tab most likely registers a `mouseExited Event` and stops the highlighting of the tab. so the tab will flicker when you move your mouse over the tab.

my question now is:
Is there a way (without implementing a new highlighting mechanism) to highlight the tab, where the custom tabComponent is located?

Comment: By highlighting, you mean, getting the focus?

Comment: @TamasRev : No. It might be specific to Nimbus LAF. I'm not sure how the other LAFs behave regarding this issue. the tabs can be in different states (at least that's how it seems as simple user). focused mouse outside the tab region (color 1), focused mouse inside the tab region (color 2), unfocused mouse outside the tab region (color 3), unfocused mouse inside the tab region (color 4). what i ment with highlight is when the user moves the cursor over a tab which changes the color of the tab. with a custom tabComponent there will be some flickering when moving the mouse over the component.

Answer (score 2):

- Here's my attempt:

  - Using a `JLayer` to dispatch the `MouseMotionEvent` from the tabs to the parent `JTabbedPane`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class TabbedExample2 extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      createUI();
    });
  }
  public static void createUI() {
    try {
      for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf: UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tab Test");
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(256, 200));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new TabbedExample2());
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public TabbedExample2() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField(16));
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField(16));
    pane.addTab("tmp", new JTextField(16));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
      tabPanel.setOpaque(false);
      //tabPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      tabPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tabPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      JTextField textField = new JTextField("Tab " + i);
      //textField.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
      //textField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
      //tabPanel.add(label); //???
      tabPanel.add(textField);
      tabPanel.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
      pane.setTabComponentAt(
          i, new JLayer<JPanel>(tabPanel, new DispatchEventLayerUI()));
    }
    add(pane);
  }
}

class DispatchEventLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {
  @Override
  public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
      //TEST:
      //((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(
      //    AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(0);
    }
    super.uninstallUI(c);
  }
//   //TEST:
//   @Override
//   protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
//     dispatchEvent(e);
//   }
  @Override
  protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
    dispatchEvent(e);
  }
  private void dispatchEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    Component src = e.getComponent();
    Container tgt = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTabbedPane.class, src);
    tgt.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(src, e, tgt));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you sultion. It is working in the example. Unfortunately, I'm working with a way more complex application and it can't be integrated that easily. Anyway, the part that does the magic i was looking for is in your method `dispatchEvent(MouseEvent e)`. If I ignore the whole JLayer part and simply use the `dispatchEvent` method i get it easily to work with the JTextField. Unfortunately, I have a custom component (instead of the JButton), which doesn't work with the code when passing the custom components MouseEvent to the `dispatchEvent?` method

Comment: Part #2: The only difference i can see (when using `system.out.println` with `tgt`, `src` and `event` that tgt contains a slightly different value of: `javax.swing.JTabbedPane[,0,0,1024x800, invalid, layout=...`. The difference is the keyword `invalid`. but i must admit, i completely have no idea what's wrong and why it isn't working. any suggestions?